# C#: Creating XML document using Linq having not proper output?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to create xml data from my data, creation was successfull but the output is bad how can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

```
private void btnGenerate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XElement xml = new XElement("Navigation",
            new XElement("NavigationSets"));
        foreach (DataRow row_navs in GetNavigationSets().Rows)
        {
            xml.Add(new XElement("NavigationName", row_navs["name"].ToString()));
            foreach (DataRow row_sets in GetMenusInNavigationSetByNavigation(2).Rows)
            {
                if (int.Parse(row_sets["id"].ToString()) == int.Parse(row_navs["id"].ToString()))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row_menus in GetMenuById(int.Parse(row_sets["menu_id"].ToString())).Rows)
                    {
                        xml.Add(new XElement("MenuName", row_menus["name"].ToString()));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        xml.Save("data.xml");
    }
```

Im expecting an output like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Navigation>
    <NavigationSets>
        <NavigationName>
            <MenuName></MenuName>
        </NavigationName>
    <NavigationSets/>
</Navigation>
```

In my current code my output is like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Navigation>
    <NavigationSets/>
        <NavigationName></NavigationName>
    <MenuName></MenuName>
</Navigation>
```

Comment: That's not valid XML. `<MenuName>` would be either `<MenuName/>` or `<MenuName></MenuName>`.

Comment: sorry check it ! updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at when you're adding elements:

```
xml.Add(new XElement("NavigationName", row_navs["name"].ToString()));
xml.Add(new XElement("MenuName", row_menus["name"].ToString()));
```

Where `xml` is this element:

```
XElement xml = new XElement("Navigation",
           new XElement("NavigationSets"));
```

That means `xml` is the `Navigation` element, *not* the `NavigationSets` element. I suspect you want something like:

```
XElement outer = new XElement("Navigation");
XElement inner = new XElement("NavigationSets");
outer.Add(inner);
```

... then add to `inner`.

Comment: yeh it works, now my problem is that MenuName should be inside NavigationName

Comment: @MekeniKine: Right, so apply the same logic again: when you create the `NavigationName` element, keep hold of it as a variable so you can add to it when you create the `MenuName` element.

Comment: got confused sir, can u provide me how to do it? thnaks!

Comment: @MekeniKine: You're likely to learn much more if you think about it carefully and do it yourself. Think about which element you *want* to add the `MenuName` to. Now thing about which one you *are* adding it to, and what change you need to make. Use the change I've shown for Navigation/NavigationSets as guidance.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Jon Skeets answer,

You can also use

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

to loop through lists so it is all one statement,

```
new XElement("NavigationSets",
    menus.Select(menu => new XElement("MenuName"))
)
```